# Django import export How to export just one object with selective columns

Tags: django-import-export

I have a model in which there are only aggregates of the values imported

```
class AggregateImport(models.Model):
Price = models.IntegerField
Total_Price = models.IntegerField
Collected_Date = models.Charfield(max_length=15)
```

Now import file only has price and collected date (40 rows) in it but I only want to export the total price

Comment: `fields = ('Total_Price',)` ? ([doc](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#customize-resource-options)), or override `get_export_fields()`

Comment: I tried the fields one but its not working. Will look into the function.